# Link FFMpeg in Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I want to use FFMpeg on android. I'm really new to this topic. I build libraries with this tutorial][1](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/blogs/2013/12/06/building-ffmpeg-for-android-on-x86). Now I have .so and .h files but I dont know how to use them in my project. I probably need to link it in my Android.mk file. Here is my .mk and .c file in my project:

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

LOCAL_MODULE    := ndksetup
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

native.c

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <android/log.h>

#define DEBUG_TAG "NDKSetupActivity"

void Java_com_example_ndksetup_MainActivity_printLog(JNIEnv *env, jobject this, jstring logString)
{
    jboolean isCopy;
    const char * szLogString = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, logString, &isCopy);

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "NDK: %s", szLogString);

    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, logString, szLogString);
}

jint Java_com_example_ndksetup_MainActivity_fibonacci(JNIEnv * env, jobject this, jint value)
{
    if (value <= 1) return value;
    return Java_com_example_ndksetup_MainActivity_fibonacci(env, this, value-1)
            + Java_com_example_ndksetup_MainActivity_fibonacci(env, this, value-2);
}
```

Can anyone tell me how I can use .so and .h files in my native.c file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This how you would make calls to lib files in your JNI folder from your native C file

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_*(JNIEnv *pEnv, jobject pObj) {
    char* lCodecName = gVideoCodecCtx->codec->name;
    return (*pEnv)->NewStringUTF(pEnv, lCodecName);
}
```

and this is how you link the native libraries from your Java code

```
static {
        System.loadLibrary("<native jni lib file name>");
    }
```